# Any way to see what accepted answer was unaccepted?

Tags: support

This happens occasionally where someone will mark an answer I've provided as accepted but then unaccept it within the span of today. I find it a bit annoying because I'll see my rep at one point during the day and then notice a -15 (in the overall total, not as a line item) but there is no record of what happened on the reputation for today.

Is there anyway I can find out which answer this has occurred on?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105314/186664) on [metase] you should be able to see it the next day on your profile page -> reputation -> time. But that is not available on the day it happens itself.

Comment: First world problem: *I have some many accepted answers, I don't know which one gets unaccepted when one does* >:-)

Comment: I've wanted to ask this Q for months and didn't for that exact reason 8-). But today it happened and I couldn't take it anymore. 8-)

Comment: When I look at the rep url: http://unix.stackexchange.com/reputation I don't see any -15's can anyone else confirm that they show up there?

Comment: I haven't seen them either and I know I had some unaccepted, so maybe the line at the bottom of that answer is out of date.

Comment: Maybe a SE site where users can try the effects of certain action would be helpful. Some place where I could put a fake question that you could answer and I could then accept and unaccept. Without the fake answer being deleted by other users/moderator. With a certain rep level on another SE site needed before you were allowed to try things out there. That could also help with understanding what exactly happens with my suggested editors meta question.

Comment: My fault, I shamelessly posted an [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116129/22222) and stole your hard earned check mark :)

Answer (score 1):

You could grab https://unix.stackexchange.com/reputation routinely and diff it.

Comment: That might be my plan B 8-)